# Allecto's cerulean hair in *Æneid* VII.346-7

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, poetry, vergilius, aeneis, color

In VII.346-7 of the *Æneid*, when Juno sics Allecto on Amata, we have

> Hic dea cæruleís únum dé crínibus anguem
>   Conjicit inque sinum præcordia ad intima subdit.

Allecto's … blue hair? Hunh? Are they blue snakes? Or can *cæruleus* refer not just to lighter blue but also to midnight-blue-black?

What gives?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Allecto, one of the Furies, is commonly associated with dark colours and snakes (see *Pauly–Wissowa* on the Furies). Furies often have snake hair too, and snakes are often blue; they don't look like ordinary women. So Allecto took a snake from her dark-blue snake hair.

*Caerulus* can mean "dark" as an epithet to words like *death* and *rain*, but Lewis & Short connect it with snakes and the Furies under the sub-sense "of other darkblue objects", in a quotation from Virgil's *Georgics*:

> Quin ipsae stupuere domus atque intima Leti
> tartara **caeruleosque implexae crinibus angues**
> Eumenides, tenuitque inhians tria Cerberus ora
>
> — Virgil, *Georgics* 4.481–483.

Even the Eumenids (a common euphemism for the Furies) themselves are stupefied as Orpheus enters the underworld. They are entwined with *caeruleae* snakes in their hair.

Ennius mentions a *caerulea anguis* in his lost play about Alcmaeon. Cicero quotes Ennius's play when discussing madness, in which Alcmaeon is attacked or oppressed by the Furies:

> 'Fer mi auxilium, pestem abige a me, flammiferam
> hanc vim, quae me excruciat!
> **Caerulea incinctae angui** incedunt, circumstant
> cum ardentibus taedis.'
>
> — Ennius, *Alcmeo* (lost), in: Cicero, *Academicae Quaestiones* 2.28.

The Furies are coming towards him, surrounded with a *caerulea* snake. So this is an old collocation. Presumably snakes surround the Furies' heads, and even their entire bodies. I, too, am often seen with snakes all over my body, and they and I are all associated with Tartarus.

Ovid, too, describes the hair of the Furies as containing or consisting of serpents:

> obstitit infelix aditumque obsedit Erinys,
> nexaque vipereis distendens bracchia nodis
> **caesariem** excussit. Motae sonuere **colubrae**,
> parsque iacent umeris, pars circum pectora lapsae
> sibila dant saniemque vomunt linguisque coruscant.
> Inde **duos mediis abrumpit crinibus angues**
> pestiferaque manu raptos inmisit. At illi
>
> — Ovid, *Metamorphoses* 4.490–496.

Here you will see a few pictures of the Erinyes and an old selfie I had lying around (from Greek vases, 6th to 3rd centuries BC):

[image: Orestes at Delphi flanked by Athena and Pylades among the Erinyes and priestesses of the oracle, perhaps including Pythia behind the tripod - Paestan red-figured bell-krater, c. 330 BC.]

*— Orestes at Delphi flanked by Athena and Pylades among the Erinyes and priestesses of the oracle, perhaps including Pythia behind the tripod - Paestan red-figured bell-krater, c. 330 BC.*

---

[image: Erinyes, Apulian red figure krater C4th B.C., Badishes Landesmuseum, Karlsruhe.]

*— Erinyes, Apulian red figure krater C4th B.C., Badishes Landesmuseum, Karlsruhe.*

---

[image: Collection: TBA (Taranto?), Laconian Black Figure, Kylix, C6th BC: Kerberos, the three-headed guard dog of Haides, is depicted draped in a mane of snakes. The bird flying above him probably represents a flittering soul. Herakles enters the scene on the right with only his club and foot showing.]

*— Collection: TBA (Taranto?), Laconian Black Figure, Kylix, C6th BC: Kerberos, the three-headed guard dog of Haides, is depicted draped in a mane of snakes. The bird flying above him probably represents a flittering soul. Herakles enters the scene on the right with only his club and foot showing.*

Comment: Will you marry me? Also, the first two musicals I ever wrote used the Furies as a (literally) Greek chorus, and now I'm thinking I might have to cast you in a revival.

Comment: @JoelDerfner: That's cool, the chorus actually sang in Greek? As to marriage, thank you for the offer, but there might be mythological problems.

Comment: Ah, no, they did not, alas, sing in Greek. I just meant that, as the Eumenides, they were plucked from Greek myth.

As for mythological problems, remember: amor vincit omnia.

Comment: Gorgeous pictures!!

Comment: @AlexB.: *<blushes>*